# Why does a routing table on my Android device has two almost equal entries (different metrics)?

Tags: android, routes, ip

Please take a look at the screenshot. There are two entries for the destination network 192.168.1.0[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Backup Routes**
In our Networking stack, Layer 3 switch will always use the route with the lowest metric. If this route becomes unavailable, the Layer 3 switch will fail over to the static route with the next-lowest metric, and so on. More than one entry will work as a backup in the case of first one's failure.

Comment: If there is an official specification about what you said, please add the link. Then I'll accept your answer

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev: This answer does not explain why there is a duplicate. There is no use in switching over to a static route with the next lowest metric if _it's exactly the same route_.

Comment: @SilverlightFox: enlighten me